# Transformer#transform(Source, Result) throws FileNotFoundException?

Tags: java, xml, filenotfoundexception, transformer-model

I am trying to output my XML Document using `Transformer.transform(Source, Result)`, but it does not export the Document, only throws a `FileNotFoundException`. I am trying to export it to `/WebContent/samples/users.xml` in my project with Apache Tomcat. After some work on Google, I found [this](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=5077403) page on the supposedly "bug" on [bugs.sun.com](http://bugs.sun.com).

Here is a selection of my code:

```
Document doc = newDocument();
Element rootElement = doc.createElement("homeworkManager");

Element sampleUserElement = doc.createElement("user");
// (set username and password)

Element sampleHomeworkElement1 = doc.createElement("homework");
// (set homework attributes)

sampleUserElement.appendChild(sampleHomeworkElement1);
rootElement.appendChild(sampleUserElement);
doc.appendChild(rootElement);

// HomeworkManager.getRealPath(String) is the same as  HttpSession.getServletContext().getRealPath(String)
File output = new File(HomeworkManager.instance().getRealPath("/") + "/samples/users.xml");

        
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");

transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(output));  // EXCEPTION THROWN HERE
```

Here is the Stack Trace:

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ...\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Homework Manager\samples\users.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.getOutputHandler(TransformerImpl.java:493)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:302)
at net.dean.homeworkmanager.UserManager.createSampleXMLFile(UserManager.java:215)
at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:91)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: (...)\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Homework Manager\samples\users.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:104)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.getOutputHandler(TransformerImpl.java:466)
... 25 more
```

As you can tell, I am very confused. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**: This has only occurred on Web Projects. I can use the exact same code to export my Document on a desktop application.

**EDIT 2**: Even when I have created the directory *and* `users.xml`, the file is not modified. It is instead created in `(...)\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Homework Manager\samples\users.xml`

Comment: Are you sure that the samples directory exists?

And you should use `HomeworkManager.instance().getRealPath("/samples/users.xml")`

Comment: The samples directory does not exist. I was using `getRealPath("/")` because that would give me the base directory, then I would add on the `/samples/users.xml` to give me the location. I have tried creating the directory also, with the same result.

Comment: @EDIT2:

That is the expected behavior. Eclipse deploys your webapp into `(...)\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\`, and of course it is then modified/created there.

Comment: @DoubleMalt Is there any way I can get Eclipse to copy the file over to the workspace?

Comment: No. 
You could of course make it an absolute path (but this is not a recommendation for obvious reasons).
The "right" way to do that is not store stuff in the context directory. Also because it will give you headaches when you want to update the application. 
Instead you use the directory your OS uses for program data. (`/var/lib/<program name>` under Linux for example.